# Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int (Between)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I am trying to get records inbetween two dates, however when I run the SQL I get the following error:

Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int

```
SELECT M.Id, M.MTimeInt, M.Date, CAST(D.Name AS TEXT) as Name 
FROM C 
JOIN N ON C.N_Id=N.Id 
JOIN M ON M.N_Id=N.Id 
JOIN MDish ON MDish.M_Id=M.Id 
JOIN D ON D.Id=MDish.D_Id 
WHERE C.Id=110 AND M.Date BETWEEN 2012-05-28 AND 2012-06-08
```

The SQL looks correct, but I can't seem to figure out why it is complaining, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The date should be enclosed in ""

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
BETWEEN '2012-05-28' AND '2012-06-08'
```

Otherwise it's `2012 minus 05 minus 28`, which equals `1979` and is an integer and not a date.

Comment: Sigh, hate it when the error is as simple as a syntax error, thanks!